# button pressed effect when another button is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

in my WP7 app using silverlight controls,

I have two buttons, 
I want to make when I press a button, the other button seems like it's also being pressed (change of color to invert...etc)

something like the native keyboard on wp7 phones when the larger button appear above your thumb

I tried to give both of them the focus, but it's not possible

-Detailed Explanation-

usually, when you press a button, the button style changes according to the theme,

ex: if theme is dark, the button becomes white and the text becomes black. but if the theme is white, the button becomes black when clicked.

My aim is to mimic that behavior to a button when another button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the click event you could use

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(Button1, "Pressed", true);
```

however to go back to the `Normal` state you would have to know when the *click* is over. LeftMouseButtonUp does not work because there is no mouse.

So you could set a timer and revert the state. Ugly but it works.

On a side note: I suspect the design you might want to use a different way of getting the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much wp7 development but I believe the normal, active and pressed appearances are implemented as different states of the button and you can programatically set the state. This article should explain it in a bit more detail but the advantage of this approach over manually setting background colours is that it should automatically take advantages of any transitions configured between those states, as well as the black => white, or white => black theme related changes will be done for you too.

http://www.timmykokke.com/2010/11/using-visual-states-in-custom-controls-in-silverlight/

Answer (score 0):

Update:
In the click handler of one set the background property of the other.

Comment: this doesn't work, this is not about the background color, it's about the style change when you press the button... it differs according to the theme applied.

Comment: So you want button 2 theme to change when button 1 clicked?  Only during touch?  Guess a little more explanation is needed.

Comment: usually, when you press a button, the button style changes according to the theme ,ex: if theme is dark, the button becomes white and the text becomes black. but if the theme is white, the button becomes black when clicked. my aim is to mimic that behavior to a button when another button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

```
Button button1
ToggleButton button2

Button1.MouseDown:
    Set button2 pressed state to true

Button2.MouseUp:
    Set button2 pressed state to false
```

Comment: You can only get the pressed state, not set it

Answer (score 0):

try using MS Expression Blend to customize the behavior, [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613593.aspx)